# Grafana - show only the latest values

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have iPad battery levels on Grafana, but I want to keep displaying just recent values.

But Every time I push the new data to InfluxDB, it just adds them. I don't want to see a million gauges, just 4. (I can manually setup the limit to 4, but that wouldn't scale...) Does it make sense?

(H.2, H.3, H.4 & H.5 are iPads names)

[image: ipads]

[image: table]

Answer (score 0):

In your Grafana InfluxQL query use `last` selector and `GROUP BY` tag `name` (`name` must be a tag, not a field). Example:

[image]

Comment: I don't have the name option there - https://ibb.co/tYGdjMp

Comment: @PavolBujna so `name` is InfluxDB `field` and not InfluxDB `tag` in your case. Please check InfluxDB documention to see difference. Ingest it as a `tag` not a `field`.